# Slope Optimization for Paraboloid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Refer to [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353732/slope-of-a-paraboloid-given-a-point-and-angle) for background information.

I am trying to optimize the slope of the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ at point $(a,b)$ with direction $\theta$. We know that the slope of the function with these conditions is $2a\cos(\theta)+2b\sin(\theta)$. I am trying to figure out what direction I need to turn from the given $\theta$ in order for the slope to be the largest. Same for the slope to be the smallest.

My thoughts thus far are simply to take $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left[2a\cos(\theta)+2b\sin(\theta)\right]$ and set it equal to zero, solving for $\theta$. Then you can just subtract that from the given $\theta$ to find the angle necessary to turn. I do not, however, think this is correct. An explanation for why something of this nature would work $\textbf{or}$ an original solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient vector is given by
$$\nabla f(a,b)=\left\langle f_x(a,b),f_y(a,b)\right\rangle.$$

The direction *vector* of the gradient can be found by dividing the gradient by its magnitude

$$\mathbf{u}=\frac{\nabla f(a,b)}{\Vert\nabla f(a,b)\Vert}=\langle\cos\psi,\sin\psi\rangle$$

where $\psi$ is the direction *angle* of the gradient.

The directional derivative in the direction $\theta$ at $(a,b)$ is the dot-product of the gradient and the direction vector $\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle$

$$ D_\theta(a,b)=\nabla f(a,b)\cdot\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle$$

The dot-product between two vectors $\mathbf{U},\mathbf{V}$ is given by

$$ \mathbf{U}\cdot\mathbf{V}= \Vert\mathbf{U}\Vert\cdot\Vert\mathbf{V}\Vert\cos\phi$$

where $\phi$ is the angle between the two vectors.

So the angle $\psi-\theta$ between the gradient vector $\nabla(a,b)$ and the direction vector $\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle$ satisfies the equation

\begin{eqnarray} \nabla f(a,b)\cdot\langle \cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle&=&
\Vert\nabla f(a,b)\Vert\cos(\psi-\theta)\\
D_{\psi-\theta}f(a,b)&=&\Vert\nabla f(a,b)\Vert\cos(\psi-\theta)
 \end{eqnarray}

As a result, when the directional derivative is taken in the direction $\theta=\psi$ it takes on its maximum value $\Vert\nabla f(a,b)\Vert$ since $\cos0=1$ and when the direction derivative is taken in the opposite direction of $\Vert\nabla f(a,b)\Vert$, the directional derivative takes on its smallest value -$\Vert\nabla f(a,b)\Vert$ since $\cos\pi=-1$.

To find the angle $\psi-\theta$ between $\theta$ and the gradient one just solves

$$ \cos(\psi-\theta)=\frac{\nabla f(a,b)}{\Vert\nabla f(a,b)\Vert}\cdot\langle \cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle $$

for $\psi-\theta$.

Comment: The gradient *always* points in the direction of greatest slope. The directional derivative at a point can point in any direction, but will have the greatest magnitude when it points in the same direction as the gradient. $\psi$ is the fixed direction of the gradient, whereal $\theta$ is the direction of the directional derivative.

Comment: I am confused about the process. We are trying to find the angle at which the slope is maximized, given a point $(a,b)$ (figuring out the turn from the given angle $\theta$ is just a matter of subtracting one angle from the other). This answer implies that $\psi$ is the angle at which the slope is maximized—if this is the case, why?

Comment: Yes, the gradient always points in the direction of the greatest slope. $\psi$ is the value of $\theta$ which maximizes the slope because $\cos(\psi-\theta)$ has its largest value, a value of $1$, when $\psi-\theta=0$, that is, when $\theta=\psi$.

Comment: So what we are actually computing is the directional derivative at $\theta$, but need the gradient to figure out what to set $\theta$ to in order to find the max/min slope? I suppose my question then would be how to find the maximum and minimum slopes given a point and no angle. Would I just find the gradient using the point $(a,b)$, then take the directional derivative with that value set as the angle? Then for the minimum slope, do the same but with $\Vert\nabla f(a,b)\Vert$?

Comment: What is the point of the directional derivative if we already have the unit vector for the angle at which the slope is maximized?

Comment: Yes, the maximum directional derivative will always be the derivative taken in the direction of the gradient and the minimum will be taken in the opposite direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133295/discussion-between-malachi-and-john-wayland-bales).

Comment: Your minimization of the slope gives the same slope but pointing in the opposite direction, making it minimal by multiplying the previous by $-1$. How would one find the minimized value of $\left | \text{Slope}\right |$?